# Should I apply again on German Embassy?

Tags: visas, germany

I am a businessman. I had applied UK tourist visa in 2017 along with my wife which were refused. Then later in December 2017 I had applied German Visa without my wife for business. Which were also refused.
After that I changed my circumstances and re applied for UK tourist visa in 2018 which were approved for both of us. We visited UK and returned back after 10 days.
We both have traveling in other more countries like Singapore, Turkey, Malaysia, Dubai, China etc

Now question is :
I want to apply schengen Visa for tourist. My wish to visit German, France, Italy and Switzerland. should I apply again on German Embassy? Or other embassy
Please guide on it

This question is NOT duplicate.  Some people told me that we should apply in German embassy because they refused me first. Other embassy will not approve my vise due to this.
This is my question now should I apply again on German Embassy? Or other embassy

Comment: "you should apply because they refuse you first??".... äh?

Answer (score 5):

You should follow the rules an apply to the country that is the main destination of your trip! If you try going on a trip very different from the one described in your visa application, you might get your visa cancelled when you try to enter, and possible be charged for deception.

If your circumstances had changed enough for the UK to grant you a visa, there is a chance that the German embassy will also grant you a visa, there is no way for us to tell.